# How to embed Swiper styles in main CSS file built by Vite?

Tags: javascript, sass, vite, swiper.js

I'm working with a classic multi-page Laravel project using SASS and Javascript modules and I'm using Vite to build CSS and JS files. After compiling, a single CSS, and a single JS file created.
Yesterday I installed Swiper JS package and imported it in one of my JS modules as specified on Swiper Getting Started page:

```
// home.js

import Swiper from 'swiper';
import { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper/modules';

import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';

// init Swiper:
export const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    ...
});
```

But after compiling, I found that a second separate CSS file containing Swiper styles is built by Vite.
Then, I tried to import Swiper SCSS into my SCSS from `node_modules` folder:

```
// _swiper.scss

@import 'swiper/swiper';
@import 'swiper/modules/navigation';
@import 'swiper/modules/pagination';
```

The styles imported fine, I see them in compiled CSS file, but Vite immediately stops working with the following error:

`Error: Missing "./swiper" specifier in "swiper" package`

What do I have to do to put Swiper styles into my main CCS file without creating another file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved after I specified full relative paths in `@import` directives in scss file:

```
@import '../../../node_modules/swiper/swiper.scss';
@import '../../../node_modules/swiper/modules/navigation.scss';
@import '../../../node_modules/swiper/modules/pagination.scss';
```

Also, I removed all `import` directives from home.js module. Now only single CSS file is created by Vite.

It is weird though that the Bootstrap imported fine from the `node_modules` just like that:

```
@import 'bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
```

And it works fine.